# How to test redux-saga's generator that calls external api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-saga

I'm complete beginner when it comes to writing tests, yet I have been given task to test some api's implementation, which is done using redux and redux-saga. The scenario is that user fills prepared form with his username, password and my generator function "authenticateUser" calls proper endpoint from api (api handlers were automatically generated from Swagger, and are imported from private registry), to create token and check whether user exists in database. If so, token is saved to session/local storage and store is updated with corresponding values.

```
import { userAuthenticated, userAuthenticationRejected } from "../actions/user";
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import createApi from "@my-module";

export function* authenticateUser(action) {
  const myApi = yield call(createApi, {
    cors: true,
    securityHandlers: {
      Basic: () => true,
      Bearer: () => true
    }
  });

  try {
    const response = yield call(myApi.token_create, {
      data: {
        username: action.payload.username,
        password: action.payload.password
      }
    });
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const body = yield call([response, "json"]);
      const accessToken = body.access;
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
      if (action.payload.persistAuthenticationToken) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
      }

      yield put(
        userAuthenticated({
          username: action.payload.username,
          accessToken
        })
      );
    } else {
      throw new Error("Unauthorized");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(userAuthenticationRejected());
  }
}
```

I got completely lost while reading about testing approaches. I've tried simple unit testing with consecutive "generator.next().value" but after first yield it couldn't even get into "try" block and throws out "undefined" sooner than expected.

```
test("User authentication", () => {
  const action = {
    payload: {
      username: "test",
      password: "test"
    }
  };
  const generator = cloneableGenerator(authenticateUser)(action);
  console.log(generator.next().value);

  // {
  //   '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
  //   combinator: false,
  //   type: 'CALL',
  //   payload: {
  //     context: null,
  //     fn: [Function: createApi],
  //     args: [ [Object] ]
  //   }
  // }

  console.log(generator.next().value);

  // {
  //   '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
  //   combinator: false,
  //   type: 'PUT',
  //   payload: {
  //     channel: undefined,
  //     action: { type: 'USER_AUTHENTICATION_REJECTED' }
  //   }
  // }

  console.log(generator.next().value);

  // undefined

});
```

When I looked at integration tests, which seems to be preferred way, I couldn't just simply transfer relatively straightforward examples to my specific case.

I'll appreciate any help, because I just don't know where to start.

Comment: Cant you just mock your @my_module? The rest should just work. I used to work with this lib which was giving a better result but thats up to you https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to pass in a mock value for your response object. I presume it’s undefined and your code throws if `response.status` is anything other than 200. So for your se one call to `generator.next().value` pass in a mock like so:

```
const responseMock = {
    status: 200,
     // anything else it needs
}
console.log(generator.next(reponseMock).value)
```

Comment: I've followed your valuable advice, which resulted in me digging deeper into javascipt's generators, which I seemingly didn't understand at the time of writing my question. I kind of managed to pass proper attributes to the next() and mock "response", but cannot do the same with mocking "body", that I try to parse as JSON (const body = yield call([response, "json"])). Every time it throws error and rejects authorization.

Comment: I’m not sure the syntax is right. I don’t think you need to pass in an array. Instead, I think it’s the function first, and then the data. Since json is a method on response (and you don’t have any args that need passed), you might have to bind it when you pass it to call. So `call(response.json.bind(response))`

Comment: Also, make sure that your mock has a `.json` method that will return a promise.

Comment: You were right about that syntax. It wasn't explicitly wrong I guess, but wasn't proper for my case. I managed to have it working with kind of a workaround:
```const parseResponse = res => res.json();
const body = yield call(parseResponse, response);
```